# Firebase (@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) return nothing

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a login and register page for my application on android studio with Firebase and I have a problem when I'm creating an account. My task doesn't get what I am supposed to have.

```
package com.example.wheretowork;

public class Inscription extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editTextEmail, editTextMdp;
    Button btnInscription;
    TextView clickConnexion;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

        btnInscription.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email, mdp;
                email = String.valueOf(editTextEmail.getText());
                mdp = String.valueOf(editTextMdp.getText());

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                    Toast.makeText(Inscription.this,"Entrez votre email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mdp)){
                    Toast.makeText(Inscription.this,"Entrez votre mot de passe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, mdp).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                    Toast.makeText(Inscription.this, "Compte créé.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Connexion.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                } else {
                                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                    Toast.makeText(Inscription.this, "Compte non créé.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Do you have an idea why my task isn't returning anything?

`public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)`

I have used logs and I saw that's my Email and Mdp (pwd) were found.
However the exact problem is that this line of code (under) always return false, and so my userAccount is never created.

`if (task.isSuccessful())`

[LOG.screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WysWL.png)

I would know if someone know why it never return true

Thx for ur answer.

Comment: What do you mean "not returning anything"?  Please edit the question to explain in more detail what exactly isn't working the way you expect. You could also add some logging statements and share the output to illustrate.

Comment: Have you thought about adding an onFailureListener to see if that gets triggered? It would allow you to see the error (if one exists).

Comment: @DougStevenson i just edit the question

Comment: @tomerpacific has a point - you're not checking for errors at all, so you would never know if something is going wrong.